# checkbox with display tag not working first time

Tags: checkbox

I am using the below code to display a table in jsp with display-table and having a checkbox , but its not working in IE7 first time . can any one help.

```
 <display:column title="Match 
      <acronym title='Select/Deselect All'>
        <input type='checkbox' name='checkall' onclick='checkUncheckAll(this);' id='arResults'/>
      </acronum>" class="center">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have js files in your site try change position like if you have ui.js move it or if you have javascript move it to the footer